# ngIf with multiple || (OR) conditions not working

Tags: angular

I'm having trouble setting up a multiple-condition ngIf. It works when nesting `<ng-container>`s with one condition each, but doesn't when I try to use just one container with all conditions together.

Code:

```
// This doesn't work
<ng-container *ngIf="
      !(estadoReparacionValue === 'ANULADA') ||
      !(estadoReparacionValue === 'ENTREGADO') ||
      !(estadoReparacionValue === 'ENTREGADO PARA BAJA') ||
      !(estadoReparacionValue === 'DERIVADO A REZAGOS P/BAJA')">
    <!-- Things happen here -->
</ng-container>


// This doesn't work either
<ng-container *ngIf="
    estadoReparacionValue !== 'ANULADA' ||
    estadoReparacionValue !== 'ENTREGADO' ||
    estadoReparacionValue !== 'ENTREGADO PARA BAJA' ||
    estadoReparacionValue !== 'DERIVADO A REZAGOS P/BAJA'">
    <!-- Things happen here -->
</ng-container>


// This works
<ng-container *ngIf="estadoReparacionValue !== 'ANULADA' ||">
    <ng-container *ngIf="estadoReparacionValue !== 'ENTREGADO'">
        <ng-container *ngIf="estadoReparacionValue !== 'ENTREGADO PARA BAJA'">
            <!-- Things happen here -->
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

The variables and condition check work fine, since the last example actually works, but it doesn't work at all when I do it similarly to the first two examples.

In short, I want to have the ngIf work with just one `<ng-container>`

Comment: You need AND, not OR.

Comment: See comment from tkausl. Use `&&` everywhere you have `||` in the first two container definitions

Comment: @tkausl 's suggestion seems to work fine, but why? I'm supposed to check if at least one of these don't exist, not all at the same time. Am I missing something?

Comment: remember the view should not conflict with the logic, you literally want to apply logic in the view.

Comment: Good point, I took @maury844's suggestion as an example of that. It's probably the better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do the <s>`OR`</s> `AND` in the component.ts and then you ask for the variable in the HTML?

```js
get shouldShow() {
  return estadoReparacionValue !== 'ANULADA' &&
    estadoReparacionValue !== 'ENTREGADO' &&
    estadoReparacionValue !== 'ENTREGADO PARA BAJA' &&
    estadoReparacionValue !== 'DERIVADO A REZAGOS P/BAJA';
}
```

```
<ng-container *ngIf="shouldShow" > 
  ... 
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need check with `&&` as tkausl pointed out, then the resulted condition will be..

```
<ng-container *ngIf=" estadoReparacionValue &&
    estadoReparacionValue !== 'ANULADA' &&
    estadoReparacionValue !== 'ENTREGADO' &&
    estadoReparacionValue !== 'ENTREGADO PARA BAJA' &&
    estadoReparacionValue !== 'DERIVADO A REZAGOS P/BAJA'">
    <!-- Things happen here -->
</ng-container>
```

> I'm supposed to check if at least one of these don't exist, not all at the same time.

if I understand you properly, you can also write else block for this like

```
 <ng-container *ngIf=" condition ; else anotherBlock>

 ...
 <ng-container #anotherBlock></ng-container>
 ...
```